# Convert Military Time Separated by Pipes into Standard Time

Tags: sql, oracle

I need some help converting military time separated by a pipe into standard time. In addition I would like to know if it's possible to decode the pipe into a day of the week.

When I query for a customers hours of operation I am presented with the following result:

```
|0900|1800|0900|1800|0900|1800|0900|1800|0900|1800|0900|1300||
```

The first pipe equals Monday Open, second pipe equals Monday Closed. The third pipe equals Tuesday Open, the fourth Tuesday Closed etc. etc.

What I would like to see is something like

```
Monday: 9:00am - 6:00pm,
Tuesday: 9:00am - 6:00pm,
Wednesday: 9:00am - 6:00pm,
Thursday: 9:00am - 6:00pm,
Friday: 9:00am - 6:00pm,
Saturday: 9:00am - 1:00pm,
Sunday: Closed.
```

Is this possible to convert in Oracle?

```
select hours_of_operation
from customer_listing
where listing_id = '255990748'
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You may have to write a pl/sql function to iterate through the values, or one long select statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1e658/9) to get you started. The first day would be:

```
select 'Monday: '||
        to_char(to_date(substr(hours_of_operation,2,4),'HH24MI'),'HH12:MIAM')
        ||'-' ||
        to_char(to_date(substr(hours_of_operation,7,4),'HH24MI'),'HH12:MIAM')
from test
```

Then just add on, and move the substring function indexes.

UPDATE:  I just realized this will only work for fixed fields.  If you are missing a day, it will fail.   That really requires a function to be written to handle some of the parsing logic.

Comment: Thank you, OldProgrammer. This was the starting point that I needed. Thanks again! It worked for me.